# How to work with Cabal API

Tags: haskell, cabal

I would like to "interact" with Cabal during the test phase (like exitcode-stdio-1.0) using the relative API (https://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-latest/doc/API/Cabal/Distribution-Simple-Test-ExeV10.html) to customise for example the final output.
How can I do that? I cannot find the right documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `exitcode-stdio-1.0` test suite is only an executable, which needs to implement `main :: IO()`. Cabal test just runs the executable and captures the output in a log file. So if you use a test framework like tasty, you'll get the output the tasty way. Of course, you can just write your own executable, and output what you want. You just need to return the proper error code to tell Cabal if the tests were successful or not.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So is it not possible "piping" the output of exitcode-stdio unless I parse the file generated by cabal?

Comment: The output is also written to standard output: you see the tests running as it does, and then at the end you have the output in a log file. So you should be able to pipe the output of cabal test into something else.

Comment: So even UserHooks from the API cannot avoid that. Still I need a sort of text parsing.